# How to force BusyIndicator?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, busyindicator

I use Extended WPF Toolkit BusyIndicator

My Xaml

```
<extToolkit:BusyIndicator Name="wait" IsBusy="False" Cursor="Wait" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="10,10,10,10"/>
```

My code:

```
private void esp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    wait.IsBusy = true;

    // My work here make some time to finish

    wait.IsBusy = false;
}
```

But it never be showed, I try to make MessageBox in the end of the function the BusyIndicator be showed after the MessageBox,

I tried

```
wait.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Send,
                       (Action)delegate
{
    wait.IsBusy = true;
});
```

But I got nothing!!!
Where’s the problem here I can’t resolved it?

I found a similar question but I don't have the same problem the indicator showing up but after the complete of the function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're performing all the work in dispatcher's thread (I assume that `esp_Click` is an event handler). This effectively means that while performing long tasks, UI is not being updated.

You need to perform work in separate thread - either create a new thread, use thread pool or create a task. Set `IsBusy` to `true` before starting and to `false` after completing your work. You'll need to use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke/Invoke` when updating `wait.IsBusy` from another thread.

Sample code:

```
private void LongRunningTask() 
{
   // your long running code

   // after you complete:
   Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Send,
                           (Action)delegate
    {
        wait.IsBusy = false;
    }); 
}

private void esp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   wait.IsBusy = true; // either here, or in your long running task - but then remember to use dispatcher

   var thread = new Thread(LongRunningTask);
   thread.Start();

   // OR

   ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => LongRunningState());

   // OR, in .NET 4.0

   Task.Factory.StartNew(LongRunningTask);
}
```

Note that neither of this solutions handles exceptions - you'll have to add error handling yourself (or use task continuations in case of last sample).

Comment: and when I have to add wait.IsBusy = true; !! before my long code ?

Comment: I use some textbox in my code and I have an exception for that textbox "a different thread owns it" !!

Comment: You have to use dispatcher every time you're accessing any UI element from any thread other than dispatcher's - textboxes, busy indicator, buttons and so on.

Comment: What does one do in Silverlight 4? Can't I force the blasted thing to paint?  I'm really not performing any processing that can be isolated from the interface. :(

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
<extToolkit:BusyIndicator Name="wait" IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}" Cursor="Wait" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="10,10,10,10"/>
```

and the C#:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="IsBusy" /> property's name.
    /// </summary>
    public const string IsBusyPropertyName = "IsBusy";
    private bool _isBusy = false;

    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get
        {
            return _isBusy;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_isBusy != value)
            {
                _isBusy = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(IsBusyPropertyName);                   
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the obvious. Seriously. (I'd been wondering for a half hour why my BusyIndicator wasn't showing up. Duh.)